# How to update div with a CKEDITOR?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, html

I have a page on which I have a div that I need to be able to update with several different pieces of code.  I'm using an onClick event in a different div, which calls a js function to load in the appropriate code.

When I first bring up the page, the div has only one line:

```
<textarea name="editor1" rows="35">&lt;p&gt;Edit Area.&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
```

And I use this function to get the editor on screen:

```
function showEditor() {
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {height:'450'} );
}
```

(No, I didn't need to use a function.  This was one of my attempts to fix the issue.)

It works great, as long as it gets used first.

The problem occurs after I load another set of code into the div.  At that point, if I try to load in the editor again, I get an error that "editor1" is not defined.  The error occurs whether or not "editor1" is actually part of the new code loaded into the div.

It seems to me the Javascript doesn't know about the new "editor1" item after a new load, and therefore can't do the replace.

I need to  be able to indiscriminately load which ever routine I need into the div at any time.  What do I need to do to accomplish this?

Thanks,

Sean.

Comment: are you sure the loaded html does not overwrite the editor1 element ? and if so is a new element1 defined ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var myEditorInstance = null;
function showEditor() {
    if (myEditorInstance)
        {
          myEditorInstance.destroy();
         // and if you have issues with the above you can try this ;)
         //CKEDITOR.remove(myEditorInstance);
        }

    myEditorInstance = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {height:'450'} );
}
```

Comment: Don't use CKEDITOR.remove because it's meant for internal use and doesn't clean up the DOM. http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.html#.remove

Comment: @AlfonsoML, indeed that is what they say n the docs, but my guess from the OP description is that he is replacing the div that contains the editor (*and the subsequent dynamic code from CK*) and that is what is causing the problem... so the DOM info of the CK should be taken care of ..
Additionally that is what they propose in their forum at http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=15499

Comment: In that forum thread it's explained over and over again how to use the .destroy() method.
Using CKEDITOR.remove won't take care of other elements injected into the page like context-menus, dialogs, and the references to the DOM elements of the editor will still remain in the editor object, with event listeners... If you wanna have problems with your clients stating that the browser is eating their memory then go that way, or you could just as easily call the destroy() method and forget about that.

Comment: @AlfonsoML, hey hey .. do not get worked up .. Lots of people in that thread mention issues with the destroy method.. but i agree that it is the recommended way to go .. i will update my answer

Comment: Okay, I realized that I was probably going about the problem incorrectly.

I can load pages into the div with no problem, so I decided to create an html page that created a textarea and then loaded the editor.  Basic stuff.  So I did.

It works as long as it's loaded alone as a stand alone page.  But when I try to load it into the  div, I get the textarea, not the editor.

Any idea why?